# Programmatically adding and removing log appenders in log4net

Tags: .net, nunit, log4net

I have a component that uses log4net. I want to create unit tests, that validate that certain error conditions result in the correct logging.

I was thinking that the best way to do this is to create an ILogAppender implementation, for example a mock. I would then add the log appender to log4net during test setup, inspect what was written during test validation, and remove it again during test teardown.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have been using [the BasicConfigurator](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) configured with a [MemoryAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Appender_MemoryAppender.htm). This appender lets you get to the in-memory messages logged during your test.

Comment: I finally got to implementing this, and it solves the problem very nicely

Comment: +1; saved me from making a stub implementation of `ILog` and injecting it into all of my classes :-)

Answer (score 20):

Using the BasicConfigurator is fine for unit testing (what the OP asked for, but not what's in the subject line). The other answers grab output for a specific logger.

I wanted it *all* (this was a 'self test' page within a website). In the end I did basically the following:

```
var root = ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root;
var attachable = root as IAppenderAttachable;

var appender = new log4net.Appender.MemoryAppender();
if(attachable!=null)
    attachable.AddAppender(appender);
// do stuff
var loggingEvents = appender.GetEvents();
foreach (var loggingEvent in loggingEvents)
    loggingEvent.WriteRenderedMessage(writer);
if(attachable!=null)
    attachable.RemoveAppender(appender);
```

...but wrapped up as a Disposable as per @Pawel's approach

UPDATE: Pawel's answer was deleted, so I am adding his link here:
[Programmatically check Log4Net log](http://www.lesnikowski.com/blog/index.php/programmatically-check-log4net/).

Answer (score 3):

The following code was originally found on the [apache mailing list archives](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4net-user/200405.mbox/%3C12258958B5842E4595E5498AA241A4132992@ttntserver.telfordtech.local%3E) and should solve the problem of adding and removing log4net appenders in code

```
/// <summary>
/// dataLog
/// </summary>
protected static readonly IDeviceCommunicationsLog dataLog =
DeviceCommunicationsLogManager.GetLogger("LIS3.Data");


Each connection adds and removes a file appender programmatically:

/// <summary>
/// add connection specific appender
/// </summary>
void AddAppender()
{
    // check if logging is endabled
    if( this.IsLoggingEnabled() )
    {
        try
        {
            // get the interface
            IAppenderAttachable connectionAppender = (IAppenderAttachable)this.DataLog.Logger;
            // need some application configuration settings
            NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings;
            // get the layout string
            string log4netLayoutString = appSettings["log4net.LIS3.LayoutString"];
            if( log4netLayoutString == null )
            {
                // use default setting
                log4netLayoutString = "%d [%x]%n   %m%n  %P MessageData}%n%n";
            }
            // get logging path
            string log4netPath = appSettings["log4net.Path"];
            if( log4netPath == null )
            {
                // use default path
                log4netPath = ".\\";
            }
            // create the appender
            this.rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender();
            // setup the appender
            this.rollingFileAppender.MaxFileSize = 10000000;
            this.rollingFileAppender.MaxSizeRollBackups = 2;
            this.rollingFileAppender.RollingStyle =   RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size;
            this.rollingFileAppender.StaticLogFileName = true;
            string appenderPath = LogSourceName + ".log";
            // log source name may have a colon - if soreplace with underscore
            appenderPath = appenderPath.Replace( ':', '_' );
            // now add to log4net path
            appenderPath = Path.Combine( log4netPath, appenderPath );
            // update file property of appender
            this.rollingFileAppender.File = appenderPath;
            // add the layout
            PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout(   log4netLayoutString );
            this.rollingFileAppender.Layout = patternLayout;
            // add the filter for the log source
            NDCFilter sourceFilter = new NDCFilter();
            sourceFilter.StringToMatch = this.LogSourceName;
            this.rollingFileAppender.AddFilter( sourceFilter);
            // now add the deny all filter to end of the chain
            DenyAllFilter denyAllFilter = new DenyAllFilter();
            this.rollingFileAppender.AddFilter( denyAllFilter );
            // activate the options
            this.rollingFileAppender.ActivateOptions();
            // add the appender
            connectionAppender.AddAppender( this.rollingFileAppender );
        }
        catch( Exception x )
        {
            this.ErrorLog.Error( "Error creating LIS3 data log appender for " + LogSourceName, x );
        }
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// remove connection specific appender
/// </summary>
void RemoveAppender()
{
    // check if we have one
    if( this.rollingFileAppender != null )
    {
        // cast to required interface
        IAppenderAttachable connectionAppender = (IAppenderAttachable)this.DataLog.Logger;
        // remove the appendier
        connectionAppender.RemoveAppender( rollingFileAppender );
        // set to null
        this.rollingFileAppender = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you do not use the BasicConfigurator or XmlConfigurator anywhere, you need to set Hierarchy.Configured to true to make log4net actually do anything.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger) theLogger.Logger).RemoveAppender("SomeAppender");
```

same for add.

Comment: Do you know how to make the add actually work? I've written a unit test to test the implementation of a custom appender I created, but unfortunately the Add method of Logger is a lie, because the ILog implementation that LogManager.GetLogger(string) returns has a read only collection of appenders. It ends up silently consuming the exception it throws internally, and never really adds the appender.